Failing to run dba.configureInstance against MySQL cluster 8.4 server on Ubuntu noble
I want to run the commands listed here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.4/en/check-instance-configuration.html
I've added the latest MySQL package mysql-apt-config_0.8.30-1_all.deb to install mysql-cluster-8.4-lts which works.
I've followed the instructions from here here to install mysqlsh 8.4: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.4/en/check-instance-configuration.html
This involves re-configuring the package to point at the non cluster 8.4 version in order to get access to mysqlsh 8.4.
When running dba.checkInstanceConfiguration('USER@127.0.0.1:3306') I get the following error:
ERROR: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dba.checkInstanceConfiguration('USER@127.0.0.1:3306')' at line 1


Upon reading the \help section I'm now realising there are different modes for mysqlsh. Upon logging in the default mode is \sql, but the function I want to run requires switching to \js.
